# SQL-Query with a multi-part identifier problem within a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, subquery, multipart, identifier

i've a query that is supposed to return the sum for "status"-duration entries. The duration is calculated by using datediff(n, datestamp, (subquery that returns the datestamp ending the current status, i.e. finds the next fitting "status change"-entry after the one locked at)

My Problem is that the following query returns an multi-part identifier error

- The INC table is giving me the
  "INCIDENT_NUMBER" i'm looking for wich is related to
  "NUMBER" in the other tables
- ACTM1 holds all DATESTAMP-Entries
- ACTA1 is related to ACTM1 via "THENUMBER" and it holds all the information about if an entry is an fitting status change or not

Code:

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(n, ACTM1.DATESTAMP, END_DATESTAMP_TABLE.END_DATESTAMP))
FROM INC                LEFT OUTER JOIN
  ACTM1   ON INC.INCIDENT_NUMBER = ACTM1.NUMBER  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  ACTA1   ON ACTM1.THENUMBER  = ACTA1.THENUMBER  LEFT OUTER JOIN
/**/
    (SELECT  ACTM1_1.NUMBER, ACTM1_1.DATESTAMP AS END_DATESTAMP
  FROM ACTM1 AS ACTM1_1               LEFT OUTER JOIN
/**/
      (SELECT ACTM1_1_1.NUMBER, MIN(ACTM1_1_1.THENUMBER) AS FOLLOWUP_THENUMBER
    FROM ACTM1 AS ACTM1_1_1
    WHERE  (ACTM1_1_1.THENUMBER > /**/ ACTM1_1.THENUMBER)/*I think here lies the problem*/
      AND (ACTM1_1_1.[TYPE]  IN ('Open', 'Status Change', 'Resolved', 'Closed')))
    AS FOLLOWUP_THENUMBER_TABLE
/**/
            ON ACTM1_1.NUMBER = FOLLOWUP_THENUMBER_TABLE.NUMBER)
  AS END_DATESTAMP_TABLE
/**/
            ON ACTM1.NUMBER = END_DATESTAMP_TABLE.NUMBER
WHERE ...
```

I would be grateful for any helpful comment or hint you could give me on this,

PS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left side join relation cannot reference the right side, so this is illegal:

```
SELECT ...
FROM A
JOIN (SELECT ...FROM ... WHERE ... = A.Field) AS B ON A.ID = B.ID;
```

Use the APPLY operator instead:

```
SELECT ...
FROM A
APPLY (SELECT ...FROM ... WHERE ... = A.Field AND ID = A.ID) AS B;
```

In your case would probably be like following:

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(n, ACTM1.DATESTAMP, END_DATESTAMP_TABLE.END_DATESTAMP))
FROM INC                
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACTM1 ON INC.INCIDENT_NUMBER = ACTM1.NUMBER  
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACTA1 ON ACTM1.THENUMBER  = ACTA1.THENUMBER  
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT  ACTM1_1.NUMBER, ACTM1_1.DATESTAMP AS END_DATESTAMP
   FROM ACTM1 AS ACTM1_1
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT ACTM1_1_1.NUMBER, /* MIN(ACTM1_1_1.THENUMBER) */ AS FOLLOWUP_THENUMBER
        FROM ACTM1 AS ACTM1_1_1
        WHERE  (ACTM1_1_1.THENUMBER > ACTM1_1.THENUMBER)
        AND (ACTM1_1.NUMBER = FOLLOWUP_THENUMBER_TABLE.NUMBER)
        AND (ACTM1_1_1.[TYPE]  IN ('Open', 'Status Change', 'Resolved', 'Closed'))
    ) AS FOLLOWUP_THENUMBER_TABLE
) AS END_DATESTAMP_TABLE ON ACTM1.NUMBER = END_DATESTAMP_TABLE.NUMBER
```

Obviously the MIN inside the inner query makes no sense though.

Comment: Actually it does make sense. There sometimes more than one "fitting" status change entries. Those entries are sorted by "THENUMBER" in chronological order... Anyway thanks for your further help.

Comment: I don't mean from a business point of view, but from a SQL point of view. You can't have aggregate functions mixed with non-aggregated fields (ie. ACTM1_1_1.Number) withous a group by clause.

Comment: What you probably want is `(SELECT TOP (1) NUMBER, THENUMBER ... ORDER BY THENUMBER ASC)`

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite the query to not use subqueries at all:

```
SELECT
     SUM(DATEDIFF(n, A1.datestamp, A2.datestamp))

FROM
     INC AS I
INNER JOIN ACTM1 AS A1 ON
     A1.number = INC.incident_number
INNER JOIN ACTM1 AS A2 ON
     A2.number > A1.number AND
     A2.type IN ('Open', 'Status Change', 'Resolved', 'Closed')
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACTM1 AS A3 ON
     A3.number > A1.number AND
     A3.type IN ('Open', 'Status Change', 'Resolved', 'Closed') AND
     A3.number < A2.number
WHERE
     A3.number IS NULL
```

I wasn't able to fully reverse engineer your statement. I don't know if you needed the left joins or not and I didn't see where ACTA1 was actually being used, so I left it out. As a result, you may need to tweak the above. The general idea though is to find a row with a greater number, which has the type that you need, but for which there is no other row (A3) with the right type and a number that falls in between the two numbers.

Comment: Thanks Tom, i'll try to get your approach working. ACTA1 will be used later. If got a similar query working without the SUM at the beginning. Thats where the ACTA1 came from. The report where i'm using this query sums it up later. But my current report doesn't work this way...so i needed the SUM inside my query.